# My shower doesn't turn on when I turn the diverter

Tags: shower

I have a problem with my shower.  When I turn the diverter knob no water comes out of the shower head.  I have the type of knobs that are three one for hot one for cold and the middle to turn on the shower.  What is going on and can I easily fix it?  It isn't brand new but not very old the handles about 7 years old.  It worked until recently.  Any help? please!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like there is a problem with the **diverter valve**. When you turn on the hot and/or cold water valves they flow through the diverter valve on the way to the tub spout. When you turn the diverter valve, it redirects the flow up the pipe to the shower head.

When a diverter valve malfunctions, initial symptoms usually include partial diversion, where some water comes out of the tub spout and some comes out of the shower head, it is unusual for there to suddenly be "no water out of the shower head" like you describe.

Special tools are usually required, like a shower valve socket tool which reaches deep into the wall to facilitate removal. If you want to DIY you need to give more info and post pics. If you are not ambitious, call a plumber.

Comment: I agree Jimmy they don't usually totally fail. Could the knob that connects to the valve stem be stripped?

Comment: @ed beal, good thought, that would create zero diversion. Hope OP figures it out or comes back with some info.